# Нарисовать Canvas по значениям матрицы

Tags: java, canvas

Есть матрица [500,500] с двоичными значениями, и есть canvas. Можно-ли как-то нарисовать в канвасе пиксели с цветами, соответсвующими цветам в матрице: 1 - белый, 0 - черный?
Не могу понять как в канвасе определить парметры отдельного пикселя.

Comment: Не могу понять как в канвасе определить парметры отдельного пикселя.

Comment: Если нет готового шаблона отображения матрицы, то можно создать объект изображения и его уже вывести на холст.

Comment: вы имеете в виду готовый формат типа bmp, gif? - так не подходит, много лишней информации

Comment: какой именно информации? Есть же bmp малой битности, или вы не об этом?

Comment: на вход поступает двоичная последовательность без координат пикселей, просто значения цветов, в bmp есть header и т.д. которых не будет на входе

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточняйте в следующий раз используемую технологию в тексте вопроса и в метках. Canvas есть и в awt/swing, и в javafx (а еще в android и в html), и в каждой технологии своя реализация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сам код

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

int[][] tabel= new int[500][500];
for (int i=0; i<tabel.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tabel.length; j++) {
        tabel[i][j] = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
    }
}

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,500);
root.setCenter(canvas);
GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

for (int i =0; i<tabel.length;i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tabel.length; j++) {
        if (tabel[i][j] == 0) {
            g.strokeOval(i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

матрица рандомна, пиксель закрашенный (0), пиксель пустой(1)

рисую круг диаметром 1 пиксель, возможно лучше будет квадрат

вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сумел помочь, то буду рад.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо, что значит "root"?

Comment: объект класса BorderPane, BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

Comment: ага, читаю, все по смыслу как нужно, пытаюсь запустить

Comment: Выскакивает ошибка в  "root.setCenter(canvas);" Canvas cannot be converted to Node

Comment: чего то затупил... А как получается так, что объекту canvas прилетает значение Node?

Comment: пытаюсь это выяснить... главное есть алгоритм, а сделать это вопрос времени

Answer (score 2):

немного переделал, без канвы и сцен

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D gr2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    gr2d.setBackground(Color.green);
    int[][] tabel = new int[500][500];
    for (int i = 0; i < tabel.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tabel.length; j++) {
            tabel[i][j] = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tabel.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tabel.length; j++) {
            if (tabel[i][j] == 0) {
                gr2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
                gr2d.drawOval(i, j, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И собственно скриншот:

[image: screenshot]